# How to alias a sequence of tasks?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have custom tasks in my SBT (0.12.2) project. Let's call them `a`, `b` and `c`. So when I'm in the interactive mode of SBT I can just type `a` and the task associated with `a` is executed. I also can type `;a;b;c` and the three tasks are executed in sequence; the same way something like `;clean;compile` would do. What I also can do from the interactive shell is create an alias to run them all: `alias all=;a;b;c`. Now when I type `all` the tasks are executed in an obvious manner. What I'm trying to achieve is creating this alias inside of the SBT configuration for my project.

[This section](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/TaskInputs) of SBT documentation deals with tasks, but all I could achieve was something like this:

```
lazy val a = TaskKey[Unit]("a", "does a")
lazy val b = TaskKey[Unit]("b", "does b")
lazy val c = TaskKey[Unit]("c", "does c")
lazy val all = TaskKey[Unit]("all", ";a;b;c")

lazy val taskSettings = Seq(
    all <<= Seq(a,b,c).dependOn
)
```

The problem I have with this approach is that the tasks are **combined** and thus their execution happens in parallel in contrast to sequential, which is what I'm trying to achieve. So how can I create an alias like `alias all=;a;b;c` inside of the SBT configuration file?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've been looking for the same thing and found [this request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/388) for an easy way of aliasing and [the commit](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/6746557d05b2b1c207aa5d1a03e5426694c5bf2b) that provides one: `addCommandAlias`.

In my `build.sbt` I now have:

```
addCommandAlias("go", ";container:start;~copy-resources")
```

As you might guess, writing `go` in the console will now run the longer command sequence for me.

Comment: Yeah, they are going to add a bunch of cool stuff in 0.13. You probably won't even need the full-build configuration anymore by the time it gets released.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even notice the version tag. It works for me in 0.12.1. :)

Answer (score 12):

another way to achieve this is to define an alias in your .sbtrc file which will be in the root of your project directory.

```
alias all=;a;b;c
```

you have an additional option of defining these .sbtrc file in your home directory in which case this alias will be available to all your projects.

Answer (score 9):

I've figured it out:

```
lazy val taskSettings = Seq(
    all <<= c dependsOn (b dependsOn a)
)
```

Comment: I wonder why do all that "dependsOn"-thing given that the sequence is defined already ";a;b;c" or why defining ";a;b;c" if `c dependsOn (b dependsOn a)` is set