# How to chain SBT task with multi module project

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

I have configured one SBT multi-module project with [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage#sbt-scoverage) plugin, which is working fine.

To generate test coverage, I am using `> SBT clean coverage test coverageReport` but is there any way to create a new task which chains internally `coverage test coverageReport`.

I have tried
[Run custom task automatically before/after standard task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820939/run-custom-task-automatically-before-after-standard-task) to create a custom task, but it seems not working with multimodule project.

And one more - http://eed3si9n.com/sequencing-tasks-with-sbt-sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`addCommandAlias`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435620/5205022) like so

```
addCommandAlias("coverageAll", ";clean;coverage;test;coverageReport")
```

Now executing `sbt coverageAll` should generate coverage report for all the sub-projects.

Comment: Thanks, It works fine. But can I use existing task name for alias, something like ```addCommandAlias("test", ";clean;coverage;test;coverageReport")```. When I tried this, It goes in a recursive loop.